# Windows 8 never uses more than 8 GB memory although 16 GB are apparently available

Tags: windows-8, memory-limit

I have Windows 8 64bit PC with 16 GB memory installed. All the memory is properly recognized on my Asus motherboard and also by Windows as shown in the picture below.

I like to have many browser tabs open while watching videos in the background etc. so I expected someday to max my memory.

But I have never observed a memory usage **over 8GB**. What is going on? Is Windows not configured to take advantage of all that memory, or is it some sort of memory management?

[image: Task manager showing the max memory usage observed]

Comment: Most your memory is using as a cache which is good.

Comment: Windows rarely needs more than 8GB of RAM. So it can handle your tabs and the video. If you will render something etc. Than possibly you will reach the max-memory usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is totally normal. Windows never maxes out it's memory unless you have the page file disabled while running seriously memory-intensive tasks. It's actually surprising that Windows is even using 8GB, I would expect less, given at the time you took this screencap it was only using 40% of the processor and disk activity was low.

Watching a web video is not an intensive activity for a system with 16 GB of RAM. If you really want the number go up just for peace of mind, turn off the page file and run a really complex 3D render. Even then, you probably won't approach maximum utilization because Windows manages memory (fairly) well.

Comment: Well I tend to really open a lot of browser tabs that I intend to read  later... also I am trying to push that 8 GB limit ;)

Comment: @Sébastien If you're using Chrome, you can press Shift + Esc to see just how much usage each tab has. Add em all up and you'll see how much memory chrome tabs are taking up.

Comment: Cool tip @Moses, thanks. I use Chrome occasionally but these days I'm mostly using Opera Next (which is based on Webkit but does not yet have that feature).

Comment: I was able to make 64 bit version of Opera (the previous version with Presto engine) use about 3 GB when I had many open tabs.

Comment: Nope, that's a really problem.Heavy-weight applications (like Intellij Idea) are moved to pagefile if I don't use them for an hour or two. They become very laggy when I return to them.